# What are the implications of violation of the unitarity of CKM matrix?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, weak-interaction, electroweak, cp-violation

What are the physical implications of such observation?
In other words, why is everybody concentrating on the violation of the unitarity of the CKM matrix?

Comment: New physics, beyond the standard model. There is a frightening cottage industry of speculative scenarios. For a recent item, see [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-7691-6).

Comment: CP-violation could be a pretty big deal. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0605217